# Run a command a as a certain user and multiple groups with sudo

Tags: sudo

I am trying to allow an normal user to run some applications under other UIDs for process separations.

The applications should run with certain groups permissions (like audio or cdrom).

In the `sudoers` file i can specify that a user bob can run as a non-privileged user `jailed_user` without password.

```
bob ALL=(JAILED_USERS) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

So in order to execute the command i usually use:

```
sudo -u jailed_user -g somegroup MyCommand
```

But i can specify only one group, the only other option is to preserve bob's group vector.

Is there a way i can pick the group vector with `sudo`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question in sudo mailing list, and the answer:

> Currently you can only set the real and effective gids.  There is
>   no way to set the group vector.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this idea for a long time, which lead me to this page, and I'm getting some vague idea of some ways to get around this limitation by using the sudoers file with custom scripts to permit users to modify their group memberships. It's my understanding that sg, gpasswd, and/or newgrp are/is supposed to be able to accomplish what we're trying to do, but I run into errors every time I think I've figured out how.